# Partial bolding of cell set by VBA changes randomly when double-clicking the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I use VBA code to bold fragments of text in a multi-line cell. Everything works fine except that, when I double-click on the cell after the bolding was set, the bolding "jumps" by one character to the right, as seen on the picture below:

[image]

This is the code snippet I use to bold the dates:

`rng.Characters(Start:=lngStart, Length:=lngEnd).Font.Bold = True`

I have a gut feeling that this might have something to do with the line breaks. I use a concatenation with `Chr(10)` to create them. (E.g. `strLine1  & Chr(10) & strLine2`).

I'm running Office 365, Excel Version 1908.

EDIT:

This is the code I use to bold the cells:

```
Public Sub BoldActionDates(lsoTarget As ListObject, strColumnName As String, lngDataRow As Long)

    Const LNG_LENGTH_DATE_STRING As Long = 10

    Dim colStartingPoints As Collection
    Dim varIndex As Variant
    Dim rngAction As Range

    Set rngAction = lsoTarget.ListColumns(strColumnName).DataBodyRange(lngDataRow)
    Set colStartingPoints = GetStartingPointsDateStrings(rngAction.Value)
    If colStartingPoints.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    rngAction.Font.Bold = False
    For Each varIndex In colStartingPoints
        rngAction.Characters(Start:=CLng(varIndex), Length:=LNG_LENGTH_DATE_STRING).Font.Bold = True
    Next varIndex

End Sub
```

`GetStartingPointsDateStrings` returns a Collection that contains the values of the starting points, e.g. for the example shown above the Collection looks like this:

[image]

Also, there is no BeforeDoubleClick-Event in the worksheet, only an unrelated one for BeforeRightClick.

Comment: Please publish the rest of the procedure in which the above line is embedded. What's the link between the code and the double-click? How do you calculate `lngStart` and `lngEnd` (please provide the code)?

Comment: @Variatus I edited my original post to include more of the code I use to bold the cells. There is no BeforeDoubleClick-Event in the worksheet.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. Double-click enters Edit mode. No shift of bold text occurs when I add a space. The Chr(10) LF just counts as a character. It's not included in a date of 10 Chrs length. If no code runs on double-click, and none on Change, and no change is made to the cell nothing should change. The only wild guess remaining is, why do you double-click on the cell, which is a lead-up to suggesting that you don't lol:

Comment: Can you try to add `range(rngAction).ClearFormats` before applying the bold stuff, and see if this changes your problem?

Comment: @Luuk I just tried that, but it didn't help ...

Comment: Thanks for trying..... Only option i do see is splitting this info to multiple cells....